# Why won't my Export button display the output from my fields

Tags: java, swing

New to asking questions here on stack overflow.  I have a program that has me stumped.  I have been able to get it to work but just not in the manner I would prefer and I was wondering if some of you could take a look at it and help me figure out what I am doing wrong.  Please see below:

Comment: Don't use `static` as a means to bridge classes, pass a reference of `Input` to `Output`

Comment: @MadProgrammer beat me to the punch. Yep, do as he says -- extract the data from Input and pass it into Output, or pass the Input **instance** reference into Output so that it can extract the information.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the beginning, the program doesnt compile in class *Output* at

```
    String ageStr = Input.getAge().toString();
    int ageInt = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);
```

because **getAge()** returns the address, not the Text of JTextField. Integer **can't parse** that, as it inhabits not only integers.
And so does **all** your static getters only return not intended data.

Try to change those in class *Input* after this sample:

```
    public static String getAge() {
        return age.getText();
    }
```

and don't forget to add the *outputPanel* in class *Output*

```
    add(outputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Additionally,

- make those methods **non-static** as stated by others
- separate / encapsulate code into fitting methods and improve your API

  - keep an overall persistent code appearance.

---

One option is to define an **object variable** and change your Output-Constructor:

```
Input input;     // keeps a ref to input

public Output(Input input) {
    super("Output", 300, 300);
    this.input = input;

    String ageStr = input.getAge();
...
```

And the call to:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    output = new Output(Input.this); 
    output.display();
...
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Ok I did everything you said but I'm still getting an error at ageStr.  That and I'm not real sure how I need to pass the references between code.  I was able to get everything to work as you described if I kept my fields and methods static, but I know it shouldn't be done that way.

Comment: What error do you get? Show me your *getAge()* and where you parse the string. References can be passed for example by overloading your constructors with _Input( Output output )_

Comment: Here is getAge()  public String getAge() {
    return age.getText();
    }    so do I need to overload my Input Constructor?

Comment: I changed my answer above.

Comment: Hey man you are awesome.  Thanks for helping me out with this I was having a really hard time figuring out how to get the object references correct.  You sir are awesome.  I've only just begun my software dev journey.  Thanks to all of you guys for the help and the tips on formatting.  Much appreciated.  lenhuy2106 I gave your answer above the credit.  Thanks again!

Comment: Everytime :) Glad I could help you on your journey, keep going my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I changed, like I said I'm still getting an error.  So far all I have tried to fix is the code associated with the age.  I will work the rest when i figure out how to make this work.  See new code below.  I can get it to work if I leave everything static but I know that's not the appropriate method.  Tried to fix the formatting as well.